# Two Form_For on One Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the Following

- Page Model
- Client Model
- Business Model

There is No Relationship between any of these Models.

I would like to Have on the Show Template of the Page to have the Form_for's

- One for the Client
- One for the Business

Is This Possible?

Current Have The Following:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <%= form_for (@business) do |f| %>
     <div id="contact_form_name">
     <p>Company</p>
     <%= f.text_field :company_name, :class =>'form_input_small'  %>
     <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'button' %>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
    <%= form_for (@client) do |f| %>
     <div id="contact_form_name">
     <p>First Name</p>
     <%= f.text_field :first_name, :class =>'form_input_small'  %>
     <%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'button' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Error I am Getting in the Log is the following

```
 <div id="sidebar">
    78:                                 <%= form_for (@business) do |f| %>
    79:                                         <div id="contact_form_name">
    80:                                         <p>Company</p>
    81:                                         <%= f.text_field :company_name, :class =>'form_input_small'  %>
  app/views/pages/show.html.erb:78:in `_app_views_pages_show_html_erb___1556847543_65073939124600'
  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:9:in `show'
```

Routes

```
 businesses GET    /businesses(.:format)                      {:action=>"index", :controller=>"businesses"}
                           POST   /businesses(.:format)                      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"businesses"}
              new_business GET    /businesses/new(.:format)                  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"businesses"}
             edit_business GET    /businesses/:id/edit(.:format)             {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"businesses"}
                  business GET    /businesses/:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"businesses"}
                           PUT    /businesses/:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"businesses"}
                           DELETE /businesses/:id(.:format)                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"businesses"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails doesn't really care where you have your forms so long as you provide it with the necessary information, & there's nothing that says you can't mingle various models together into a single view.

Assuming you're making use of RESTful resources(as you should), you'll have something like:

```
resources :pages
resources :companies
resources :clients
```

Setup in your routes.rb, this makes it pretty easy to specify how you want your form_fors to operate.

For instance on your show action for your Page model you could have something like:

```
<h1>New Company:</h1>
<%= form_for @company, :url => companies_path do |f| %>
...
<% end %> 

<h1>New Client:</h1>
<%= form_for @client, :url => clients_path do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Make sure you're setting the instance variables `@company` and `@client` in you pages controller show action like `@company = Company.new` & `@client = Client.new`.

In both of these cases your forms will post to the create action of their respective models. You can check out [relying on record identification](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification) for further reading.

Comment: Hi Cyle
Thanks for the reply, this is what has confused me.
Making use of Restful resources and thought that the form for's can go anywhere.

The Models i Have in my App is Client and Business (Registration Forms)

Below is what i am getting in the Log

Comment: <%= form_for @business, :url => businesses_path do |f| %>
    15:                                         <div id="contact_form_name">
    16:                                         <p>Company</p>
    17:                                         <%= f.text_field :company, :class =>'form_input_small'  %>
  app/views/ftemplates/_getregistered.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_ftemplates__getregistered_html_erb__1422578663_67722762447340'
  app/views/pages/show.html.erb:74:in `_app_views_pages_show_html_erb___1556847543_67722438021560'
  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:9:in `show'

Comment: Can't really tell what that is, I'm going to have to see a little more to help. Edit your question with your view code (just the necessary bits) and the error message you're getting.

Comment: I still don't see the error message, are you sure that's all the outpout you see? Also try explicitly adding the :url option as shown in my example, i.e., instead of `<%= form_for (@business) do |f| %>` try `<%= form_for (@business, :url => businesses_path) do |f| %>`. If you're getting the undefined variable businesses_path error message then your routes might not be setup correctly or you're not using the correct named route, look at the output of the `rake routes` command to verify.

Comment: that makes two of us confused lol
if i go to businesses/new works and routes are correct.

But for love or money it will not like the form for

Comment: it is giving undefined method 'model_name' but everywhere is correct

Comment: How are you setting the `@business` variable? You should be doing something like `@business = Business.new` in your controller action. Alternatively you should be able to change `@business` in your view to `Business.new` and that will work as well - I don't recommend that approach, however, if you wish to display validation warnings back to the user upon unsuccessful submission as that will wipe out and previously sent data by reinitializing your form builder.

Comment: Making use of `@business = Business.new` +1 for the Assistance on this but i have a feeling that it cant be done. I have change the form for to another model that i have same error. Thanks for the Help again will leave it open and see what comes in.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19779/discussion-between-cyle-hunter-and-clay)